# How can I access the history instance outside of React app with React Router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a React app that shares an external script file to build a company-wide header with vanilla JS. In that header is a logo that is dynamically bound to the root of whatever application is calling it (`location.origin`).

Capturing the click navigation and using React Router v3 instead was trivial before, since access to the browserHistory occurs wherever you're setting up the routes:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

function captureLogoClick() {
    const logoLink = document.querySelector('#company-header .logo a');

    if(logoLink) {
        logoLink.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            browserHistory.push('/');
        });
    } else {
        // Resource hasn't loaded yet
        setTimeout(captureLogoClick, 100);
    }
}
captureLogoClick();
```

With React Router v4 (`react-router-dom`), how can I accomplish this without binding the listener somewhere inside of a component and using `props.history`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can export the history object that you create and pass in to the router, and then use that directly in place of `browserHistory`.

```
// app.js

import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export const myHistory = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={myHistory}>
  <App/>
</Router>

// header.js

import { myHistory } from './app.js';

function captureLogoClick() {
  const logoLink = document.querySelector('#company-header .logo a');

  if(logoLink) {
    logoLink.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      myHistory.push('/');
    });
  } else {
    // Resource hasn't loaded yet
    setTimeout(captureLogoClick, 100);
  }
}
captureLogoClick();
```

Comment: I should have clarified that I'm using `react-router-dom` from v4 - it doesn't look like it accepts a history prop :-/

Comment: Ok, alternative: just use the browser's native window.history.pushState. If you want the compatibility that the history package provides I think you can just `createBrowserHistory()` and use that without worrying about binding it anywhere or sharing it with react-router. This is kind of a shot in the dark but try it out? I *think* it'll work without issue.

Comment: The native history doesn't trigger a rerender. I think without access to the history singleton in the router, it won't work

Comment: Ok ok, I'm going back to my original answer. Check the [BrowserRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js) source and you'll see it's easy to use the base Router in place of it. Boom, access to your global history object.

Comment: Yeah, think that's the only way :-/

I suppose it's a small use case to capture clicks from outside of a react app. Thanks!

Comment: Eh, why the frowny face? `BrowserRouter` is the thinnest convenience layer over `Router` that could possibly exist; it literally just creates the history object and then passes it down to a `Router`. All of the params you pass are part of `createBrowserHistory`'s public api. This is pretty clean!

Comment: I totally agree, I guess I was just more wanting to use the `-dom` package for posterity's sake in case new features get added.